# Email list problem

Tags: php, mysql, email

My sql query to get all the e-mail addresses from my table is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cEmail
  FROM tblUsers
  WHERE cEmail IS NOT NULL AND
        cEmail LIKE '%_@__%.__%'
```

However, when I insert the list to gmail, it's still saying there are invalid e-mails. There are over 2000 e-mails and hard to go through each one to find out the problem.

Anyway to improve my query?

Comment: What do you mean by invalid e-mail addresses -- incorrectly formatted (invalid characters) such as %#$%@%^^$.%^%^, those that look valid but do not actually exist (e.g. thisaccountdoesnotexist@gmail.com), or both?

Comment: It's gmail saying "Some addresses in the "Cc" field were not recognized." This is probably due to the e-mail formatting

Comment: Google is pretty smart when it comes to these sorts of things.  You probably won't find any documentation on their methods either.  You'll have to cull your list till it goes through and analyze those that don't.

Comment: Well, that doesn't help me. How can I ensure that the e-mail I'm SELECTing is indeed a valid e-mail address (format wise)

Answer (score 0):

You may check using regulars expressions with MySQL unsing the REGEXP operator
See : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

And find / adapt a decent email checking regular expression (Google "regexp email")
Example : `\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b`
found here : http://www.regular-expressions.info/regexbuddy/email.html